# Dropbear agent key is visible in ssh connection but fail to fetch them with ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent refused operation

Tags: ssh, openwrt, dropbear

I observe some weird behaviour with regard to use of forwarded keys.

I access my router (OpenWRT 22.03) over SSH enabling key forwarding:

```
ssh -A root@192.168.xx.yy -p 2222
```

The socket for agent connection is successfully created and has proper rights:

```
root@gw-bsb:~/.ssh# env | grep SSH
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/dropbear-19ec2148/auth-cea63dfa-6
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0

root@gw-bsb:~# ls -l  /tmp/dropbear-19ec2148/auth-cea63dfa-6
srwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jan  8 00:55 /tmp/dropbear-19ec2148/auth-cea63dfa-6
```

Key are also visible to the ssh client:

```
root@gw-bsb:~/.ssh# ssh-add -v -l
1024 SHA256:xx yy (RSA)
256 SHA256:zz yy (ED25519)
2048 SHA256:xxx iii (RSA)
```

However client is not able to use keys in real ssh connections:

```
$ ssh -v git@github.com
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent refused operation
```

OpenWRT uses a dropbear implementation of ssh client:

```
root@gw-bsb:~/.ssh# dropbear -V
Dropbear v2022.82
```

Older versions of OpenWRT didn't have problems with the key forwarding.

**How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the mixed implementation of ssh client/server.
OpenWRT used *dropbear* to serve incoming sshd connections, but OpenSSH ssh client was used to establish further connections from the session. For some incompatibility, the *ssh-agen* was able to list keys, but *ssh* client could not do it.

The fix was to remove OpenSSH ssh client, which reverted the shell to use dropbear implementation of *ssh* client.

Before the fix:

```
root@gw:~# ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022
```

So, it is not an *dropbear* client.

Both client ssh packages installed:

```
root@gw:~# opkg list-installed | grep drop
dropbear - 2022.82-2
root@gw:~# opkg list-installed | grep ssh
openssh-client - 8.9p1-1
openssh-client-utils - 8.9p1-1
openssh-keygen - 8.9p1-1
openssh-sftp-server - 8.9p1-1
```

After removing `openssh-client` package:

```
root@gw:~/router-script# ssh -V
Dropbear v2022.82
```

And yes, it worked!

```
root@gw:~# ssh git@github.com
Hi 0anton! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Thanks to Matt, author of the great Dropbear ssh package who helped me to find the solution quickly.

https://github.com/mkj/dropbear/issues/213